# stream_socket_server: Присвоить несколько IP-адресов

Tags: php, сокет, потоки-данных

Как забиндить на сокет более одного IP-адреса, а именно для `stream_socket_server` и возможно ли такое? Вариант `0.0.0.0` не подойдёт. Нужно присвоить несколько IP-адресов, но не все